# Add (right) Button to Sencha Navigation View

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I want to dynamically add a (right aligned) button to the active navigation view depending on view Im showing. Is there any proper way to do it? I found many half good examples online, but didnt get them to work. Here is what I tried:

```
Ext.define('Sencha.view.user.Login', {
extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
//fullscreen: true,
xtype: 'loginview',

requires:[
    'Ext.form.FieldSet',
    'Ext.field.Email',
    'Ext.field.Password'
],
config: {
    title: 'Log in',
    iconCls: 'use',
    cls: 'kidsbackground',
    scrollable: false,
    navigationBar: {
        items: [

        ]
    },
    items:[
        {
            xtype: 'loginform'
        }
    ]
},
addRightButton:function(button){
    var navigationBar = this.config.navigationBar;
    console.log("navigationBar: "+navigationBar);
    var rightButton = Ext.Button.create({
        xtype: 'button',
        ui: 'action',
        iconCls: 'action',
        iconMask: true,
        align: 'right' });

    console.log("rightButton: "+rightButton);
    //navigationBar.addItem(rightButton);

    var oNavigationbar = {
        docked: 'top',

        backButton : {
            margin: 7,
            docked: "left",
            ui : 'back'
        },
        items: [
            Ext.create("Ext.Button", {
                text: "Button1"
            }),
            Ext.create("Ext.Button", {
                text: "Button2",
                align: "right"
            })
        ]
    };
    this.setNavigationBar(oNavigationbar);
    /*this.setNavigationBar({
        items: [
            {
             id: 'rightButton',
             xtype: 'button',
             text: 'yes!'
             //placeHolder: 'Search...',
             //align: 'right'
             }
        ]
    });*/
    console.log("wow, no crash, really ?");
}
});
```

When I run the above code I get strange errors, one of this is this (see attachment):

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try this code (in Chrome Developer Tools' console) on the [Sencha Touch 2 Navigation View example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/production/navigationview/index.html) :

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('navigationview')[0].getNavigationBar().add({
    xtype:'button',
    text:'Right',
    align:'right'
});
```

It basically get the `navigationview`, then the navigation bar of this view and finally add the button to it.

This is the proper way to add a button to the navigation bar.

Hope this helps

Comment: Cool! Trying now. Do you know if the source code for this example is available on git hub? If yes, do you know the url ?

Comment: tested it now, worked like charm! Do you know how I remove it as well when I click the left aligned back button?

Comment: When you download Sencha Touch you get an examples/ folder with more than 20 examples.

Answer (score 1):

different way

```
var navigationView = Ext.create('Ext.NavigationView',
{
  useTitleForBackButtonText: false,
  scrollable: false,
  layout:
  {
    type: 'card',
    animation: null
  },
  navigationBar:
  {
    items:
    [
      {
        xtype: 'togglefield',
        name: 'smsmode',
        align: 'right',
        value: 0,
        disabled: true
      },
      {
        text: '',
        iconCls: 'delete',
        align: 'right',
        ui: 'back',
        listeners:
        {
          tap: function()
          {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
});
```